# How to create a user-defined exception that changes an already existing method inherited from a call?

Tags: python, exception, user-defined

I am trying to create an exception that changes a methods print message from "meow" to "Nope, scratch scratch"; but not sure where this is going wrong?

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def meow(self):
        print("meow")

class GoodCat(Cat):
    def __init__(self, name):
         super().__init__(name)

    def meow(self):     
        print("purr purr meow")
    
class BadCat(Cat):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def meow(self):
        print("hiss")
    
class VeryBadCat(Cat):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

class MyException(Exception):
    pass
    def meow(self):
        try:
            if super().meow():
                return True
            raise MyException("Nope, scratch scratch")
        except MyException as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            print("Program Stop")
```

Would appreciate an explanation with the answer please; as I have at this for some time now and simply, licking, and sticking my finger in the air at this point.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of an exception: it's a *notification*, not a modifier.

Comment: @chepner not very helpful I am afraid. I am creating trying to create a user defined notification.

Comment: The point is, you don't overload methods from your class hierarchy in a separate exception. It's not clear how you think an exception will be useful here. Exceptions are raised to indicate an *error*. Where and how do you plan to raise `MyException`?

Comment: MyException is raised when the user calls Cat. meow and the print response should be a notification.  So try should check if Cat. meow has been called and then raise MyException. This is one of the tasks set before me.

Comment: Sounds like you want `Cat` to be an abstract base class, and `Cat.meow` should just raise `NotImplemented`. Or `Cat.meow` should just call `print("Nope, scratch, scratch")` instead of raising any exception.